# Automapper erro em relacionamento

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, automapper, fluent-api

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class ListaGrupo : EntidadeBase
{
    public ListaGrupo()
    {
        Items = new List<ListaGrupoItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ListaGrupoItem> Items { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Id = " + Id + ";");
        sb.Append("Nome = " + Nome + ";");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class ListaGrupoItem : EntidadeBase
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public int ListaGrupoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ListaGrupo Grupo { get; set; }        

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Id = " + Id + ";");
        sb.Append("Nome = " + Nome + ";");
        sb.Append("GrupoId = " + ListaGrupoId + ";");
        sb.Append("Grupo: {" + Grupo.ToString() + "};");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Na configuração do EF estão assim:

```
public class ListaGrupoConfiguracao : EntityTypeConfiguration<ListaGrupo>
{
    public ListaGrupoConfiguracao()
    {
        // Chave Primária
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Propriedades
        Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(t => t.Nome).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

        // Mapeamento para as tabelas do banco
        ToTable("lista_grupo");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        Property(t => t.Nome).HasColumnName("nome");

        // Relacionamentos
    }
}

public class ListaGrupoItemConfiguracao : EntityTypeConfiguration<ListaGrupoItem>
{
    public ListaGrupoItemConfiguracao()
    {
        // Chave Primária
        HasKey(t => t.Id);            

        // Propriedades
        Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(t => t.Nome).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

        // Mapeamento para as tabelas do banco
        ToTable("lista_grupo_item");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        Property(t => t.ListaGrupoId).HasColumnName("id_grupo");
        Property(t => t.Nome).HasColumnName("nome");

        // Relacionamentos
        HasRequired(i => i.Grupo).WithMany(g => g.Items).HasForeignKey(i => i.ListaGrupoId);
        // 1 para N
        //HasMany<Estabelecimento>(i => i.EstabelecimentoTipo).WithRequired(e => e.Tipo).HasForeignKey(e => e.TipoId);
    }
}
```

Por fim no Controller estou fazendo o cast:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var x = _listaGrupoItemAppServico.BuscarTodos();
            var listaGrupoItemViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ListaGrupoItem>, IEnumerable<ListaGrupoItemViewModel>>(x);
            return View(listaGrupoItemViewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Erro no Index do controller Estabelecimento", ex);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Ao executar o Mapper.Map da um erro e a aplicação para de executar, nem no catch cai. Se no meu mapeamento eu deixo assim:

```
HasRequired(i => i.Grupo).WithMany().HasForeignKey(i => i.ListaGrupoId);
```

Ele não da erro mas cria na base um outro ListaGrupo_Id com foreign key. Já estou a dias com esse problema. Alguém já passou por isso? Já fiz downgrade do Autommaper e não resolveu.

Mensagem de erro:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll
```

Comment: olha um exemplo que causa problemas a reescrita do método `ToString()`.

Comment: Então como eu disse ao remover o parametro do WithMany ele aceita numa boa

Comment: Quando você tira a configuração `WithMany` você acaba perdendo o que?

Comment: Ele cria uma nova coluna na minha base e não obedece o que eu determinei. Por exemplo eu tenho as colunas Id, Nome, Id_grupo que estão mapeados para os meus objetos conforme citei acima. Ao eliminar os parâmetros ele cria uma quarta coluna.

Comment: Isso mesmo, porque, você reescreve o `ToString()` aonde viu isso para EntityFramework? (particularmente acho um erro e nunca vi esse tipo de implementação)

Comment: O ToString sobrescrito é da minha regra de negócio não do entity. E como eu disse quando eu removo o parametro do WithMany com toString sobrescrito ele passa numa boa.

Comment: Bom Carlos eu vou dar uma pesquisa se souber da resposta posto pra ti, eu nunca vi reescrever o método para ORM porque é a classe utilizada, mas, tudo bem eu não vou afirmar que é errado e nem certo sem testar. e talvez nem seja isso.

Comment: Ok Virgilio obrigado.

Comment: Boa tarde, var x = _listaGrupoItemAppServico.BuscarTodos(); Essa variável esta vindo de que tipo? Meu receio é o fato dele estar ainda com a sessão do entityframework, e no momento da conversão, por ela ser do tipo `iqueryable`, está realizando consultas circulares.

Comment: Eu mudo com o passar das camadas a chamada mas a base é esta:

Comment: public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                var retorno = Db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
                return retorno;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Erro método GetAll em " + typeof(TEntity).Name, ex);
                return null;
            }
        }